# Taylor Series function seperation.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Say we have a function $$ F= \frac{g}{h} $$

And we want to expand it with Taylor series keeping only second grade terms. How do we know when to expand $F$ directly or $g$ and $ \frac{1}{h} $ seperately?

Answer (score 0):

The coefficients can be found by differentiating. 
assuming that all Taylor series converge, if $F=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} F_n x^n$ then $F_n=\frac{F^{(n)}(x-x_0)}{n!}$.

Use the quotient rule to differentiate $\frac{g}{h}$. It should be routine to obtain the Taylor series for $F$ from those of $g$ and $h$:

$F=\frac{g_0}{h_0}+\left(\frac{g_1}{h_0}-\frac{g_0h_1}{h_0^2}\right)(x-x_0)+O((x-x_0)^2)$

Comment: I might not have phrased my question properly. Sometimes we expand the whole function $F$ and some times we seperately expand $ g $ and $ \frac{1}{h} $ seperately and then we multiply the series. For example when you have $ \frac{e^y}{sin(x+y)} $ you can do that right? Does it depend on the grade of the terms we wanna keep? If it is small we chose to expand the whole function while when the grade is large we chose to do otherwise?